# Adding Spring boot to existing JSP project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, jsp

We have an existing JSP project that serves a website and a REST interface. However its an old project (started in 2013) and now it does not scale well with new requirements. We would like to add Spring REST interface under the same project (sharing same tomcat and sessions) until we we migrate completely and drop the old REST interface (and the website) entirely.

Current project structure is:

- Root/

  - website/
  - rest/
  - WEB-INF/

    - web.xml
    - classes/
  - META-INF/

    - context.xml

Current rest interface is accessible via /rest/xyz.jsp

Now we would like to use Spring and migrate rest/* such that they will be accessible via /api/*

How do I integrate Spring boot into this project? what set of configuration do I need to make?

Spring boot docs and internet weren't helpful.

Comment: ok go ahead, what is the issue?

Comment: So how I can I integrated Spring into this project? I have not find any documentation around this.

Comment: there is no specific document for your case, I would just go to https://start.spring.io/ and create a demo then start copying old files to new and fix/test while doing the migration. it is not easy task.